# Netplan in Ubuntu Server 18.04. How to restart network fully?

Tags: networking, server, netplan

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS use `netplan` and `systemd-networkd` as default network config tool.

In earlier release, we can use `service networking restart`, or just `ifdown & ifup` to fully restart the network or an interface.

In 18.04, netplan tells just change the yaml file and use netplan apply .

When I change a bonding interface, just like hash policy, mtu, the `netplan apply` command doesn't make the new configuration effective.

Oh by the way, netplan shows render is `networkd`.

I search the whole internet to find a way to restart the network, but failed.

What I can do is reboot the server. This will make the new mtu and hash policy effective.

But just changing a network parameter, why i must reboot the whole server! Even a unstable windows server is not like this!

So, anyone can tell me what should I do?

List of methods I've already tried and failed:

- `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` : restarted but mtu and policy not change

Answer (score 37):

`netplan apply` does the job.

In some cases you have to reboot.

Answer (score 3):

For bond interfaces there is a problem. Currently after I modify the Netplan file, I do a Netplan apply for the Netplan to modify the systemd files. Then do a systemd restart for the changes to take effect. This has its own pitfalls.

In case the server has a nfs mounted, systemd never comes up and the network stack hangs. So we need to unmount the nfs, and restart the systemd networkd again.

Comment: upvoting as this answer guided me towards correct direction. Still netplan apply and systemctl restart systemd-networkd didnt do the job completly, I had to manually disable bond member `ip link set dev enp4s0 down` and do systemctl restart systemd-networkd